# Detect an attempt to read from opposite end of pipe/fifo in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, gpib

I am thinking of implementing a sort of daemon/service in C/C++ for linux, that would communicate with a specific gpib device through shell (using linux-gpib library).
The idea is that the daemon would scan for all existing devices and would create a file/pipe `/dev/gpib#-*` (where `*` would be their address on specified gpib bus) for each device. The use would be such as of `/dev/com#`. I could then type into command-line:

`echo "*IDN?" > /dev/gpib1-12`

which would send the "*IDN?" string to device 12 on board 1. So far it is a peace of cake...

The problem starts, when I want to retrieve data from the device. I want it to work analogically, so that

`cat /dev/gpib1-12`

would write out what has the device to say... But I can not know which command, I have sent to the device, would make the device to return a string (value) and which wouldn't. So my options are:

1. Repeatedly check (*while-loop*) if the device has anything to reply and send it to the corresponding pipe afterwards.
   *-or-*
2. Query the device only when the client program attempts to read from the `/dev/gpib#-*` pipe. This would have to be served through '*signals*' and '*waits*'.

For obvious reasons (performance and/or latency handicap) I do not want to implement solution *1*. I do not know how to do the the other thing though... I feel, that it must be possible to implement on the ol'mighty linux, but how? I did read [this](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-12.html) and I think that some spin of the function `select()` is the right way forward, but I can not figure out how to use it for my problem. I also stumbled upon [this](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/pipelogic/index.php), where the guy explains how to do something similar, yet sooo different (code *mosfet.c*).

**The question is:** how can I immediately detect and react upon an attempt to read from the other side of pipe/FIFO/file via signaling, waiting or interrupts?

Thanx for answers.

---

PS: It is half past seven in the morning here (yep another sleepless night), so please excuse my broken English...
**PPS:** Oh yes, and if anyone would already know of such gpib daemon for linux, or if the think I am asking (accessing individual devices through file I/O) would be possible via the linux-gpib library, please let me know. I did read the doc's and src's for linux-gpib, but found nothing helpful. All the linux-gpib library provides are bindings to C, Python, etc.
**PPS:** Are there maybe other alternatives to using pipes?

Comment: You're mixing a lot of stuff together. Basically, what you're looking for are POLLIN/POLLOUT events to monitor on an fd using poll()/epoll().

Comment: You need a *character device driver*, not a pipe-based daemon. 

"Run this code when someone tries to read from that file" is firmly in the device driver territory. "Scan the hardware and create a special file for each instance of this particular kind of hardware attached" is also something a device driver normally does.

Comment: Wow thanks guys... I will have a look at it as soon as I get to work... I must leave now, but both of your comments seem to be the right way to go... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a nice terminal for your gpib device, you can use python (or even better ipython).

linux-gpib comes with python wrappers (for the code look [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-gpib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/linux-gpib/language/python/Gpib.py#l33)). so in your shell open python by typing `python`
In the python interpreter you can easily communicate with the device like this

```
>>>import Gpib
>>>device = Gpib.Gpib(pad=2)
```

This opens a connection to the gpib device with the primary address 2. To communicate with it simply do

```
>>>device.write('*IDN?')
>>>device.read()
'HEWLETT-PACKARD,33120A,0,8.0-5.0-1.0'
```

To simplify it even further, use ipython instead of plain python. This gives you tab-completion and much more.